# Eclipse Kepler not loading my workspace anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

I shutdown my machine yesterday and this morning on launching my eclipse it loads without any of my projects. I have tried doing a  - clean to it to no avail. Also under the following path

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

all my projects are present. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Do you see any error message when you tried to open?

Comment: No error message is displayed

Comment: Have you tried File>Import; General>Existing Project into Workspace?

Comment: @Andy As I said the projects already exist in this path -> workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\ and importing all 87 projects/libs is not effective

Comment: I hear that they're in your workspace metadata. But you're saying they're not appearing in your IDE when you open the workspace. One of the things I would try would be to import at least one of the existing projects. If it doesn't work, you've lost half a minute. If it does work, you've found a way to address the problem. Note that you can select multiple projects to import in the dialog.

Comment: Can you delete workspace/.metadata/.lock and see if it works?

Comment: @AndyThomasLet me try that

Comment: @MindPeacedoesnt solve it

Comment: @AndyThomas I ended up using your answer (File>Import; General>Existing Project into Workspace) Although I have had to re import libs that I was referencing that were not in the workspace. You can set you comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Jaymo - Added an answer below. Sorry you had to re-import referenced libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Adapted from my comments above.]*

Try re-importing the existing projects.

Choose the menu item *File>Import...*. In the resulting dialog *Import*, choose the item *General>Existing Projects into Workspace*.

You can select multiple projects in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try below and see if it works

Go to  Window->Preferences->General->Startup ans Shutdown -> Workspaces

Make sure workspaces contains path of your workspace. If not then you have to add it manually.

Once you add workspace close your eclipse and then delete workspace/.metadata/.lock file if exist and restart it again

Note: Also make sure you have Prompt for workspace on startup checkbox is checked

[image]

Comment: That doesnt solve. I have had to import all the projects again

Comment: Good that you got solution :)