# Eclipse workspace won't show my project anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse kepler. A few minutes back I had to force restart the whole machine and then when I fired up eclipse it would momentarily show the projects and then disappear. The projects are there in the workspace folder and I can access all my files using ctrl+shift+r and even run it on the server. But I can't see the projects in the project explorer.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300192/eclipse-kepler-not-loading-my-workspace-anymore) but importing into another workspace has other issues. Like not able to configure the server, not even manually. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach a picture?

Comment: Well, it seems I have further damaged the project setup by moving out the folders. But I have managed to retrieve them by exporting it to EAR and then importing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below step while you import. Check "Copy Projects into workspace" before proceed as shown below

[image]

This will retrieve the projects

Comment: For some reason the solution doesn't work. Seems like it's missing in some dependencies plus it won't let me add any servers.

Comment: Okay, there's one change you need to do is - while importing the existing project I checked the option to **copy the project into workspace**. Now I can retrieve all my sources and add servers as well.

Comment: @VijuNil I updated my answer with that solution So it will be useful for the future visitors